# SAM Turret's Capabilities

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What kill streaks does the SAM Turret shoot down?  Can it be destroyed by air strikes, chopper gunners, or other kill streaks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can shoot down any flying vehicle except the [Stealth Bomber](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_Bomber).

It can be destroyed by aerial vehicles, or any gun, even a single knife attack will destroy it.

Note: Uncertain about the [Recon Drone](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Recon_Drone).

Comment: Even the recon drone?

Comment: @IanPugsley Haven't really tried it.

Comment: @bora do the helicopters automatically target sam turrets?

Comment: No, Turrets are not marked as a target. I noted the part that it can be destroyed by aerial vehicles only for the sake of completeness. SAM missiles are quite fast, even faster than a Valkyrie (Black Ops). A Chopper would not stand any chance against 4 guided rockets,of which at most 2 is enough to take down a heli.

Comment: It will fire on the recon drone, although you can dodge it if you're fast or it has a particularly poor angle on the drone.

Answer (score 1):

SAM Turrets will attempt to take down any Aerial Killstreak including the Recon Drone in its sights except the stealth bomber, precision airstrike and predator missiles.